# Dygraphs synchronization extension skips on other charts

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Loving Dygraphs and the synchronization extension is [almost] pure awesomeness.

But even on the example on the website, it actually skips a beat as you move around. You'll notice as you slide around, the chart you're hovering over updates each interval. But the other charts skip intervals.

At first I thought it was every other interval, but it's not. It's kind of random but it's the same as you move around. You can see the problem here:

http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/synchronize

I've looked at the extension code and I don't see any reason it wouldn't be working. FYI, for my charts (like the example) I'm using very regular data-- the same exact intervals for each chart. They are each one day so it's not like the charts are off by hours or minutes or seconds.

Comment: how strange! I'm seeing it too. Please file an issue: https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/new

Comment: Thanks @danvk. Added: https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/554